# VBA code to save Excel Worksheet as csv in "silent" mode

Tags: excel, vba, csv, save-as, silent

I am saving transactions as CSV files to a network drive. A transaction may consist of up to 3 CSV files.
Since it is a network drive this may take up to a few seconds, depending on network traffic.

So what happens is that if the user clicks the "commit" button, the screen flickers up to 3 times with each of the CSV files being saved. Technically everything works fine but I would like to suppress these operations taking place visibly on screen, and rather display a message box that disappears once the CSV's are saved to the network drive.

I can figure out the message box part, but I cannot find anything that addresses the "invisible save" part. The code that I use is:

```
Set shtToExport = WS3     'Sheet to export as CSV for Transaction
 Set wbkExport = Application.Workbooks.Add
shtToExport.Copy Before:=wbkExport.Worksheets(wbkExport.Worksheets.Count) 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Overwrite without asking
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename1 & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
'Create CSV Backup to retieve Transaction and Bonuspoint Info for transaction
wbkExport.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename2 & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
wbkExport.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

WS3, Path, Filename1 and Filename2 are defined somewhere else in the code

Any Ideas?

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` not work for you?

Comment: I'm really new to this so I have many knowledge gaps of various size and depth... - I will try this now

Comment: Seems to do the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

That should stop the screen flickers, you should set it to true afterwards however.

Let me know if that works or not
Thanks!